# Excel 2010 - Merge column range in row

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have made a simple piece of VBA code that jump to the first empty row cell in column A:

```
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RO input sheet").Range("A" & LastRow).Select
```

Next step should be to merge column A to M in this row, but I can't seem to figure out how this is achieveable. I'm aware of the .Merge method of the Range class, but can't get it to work.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few attempts available and one could be as follows:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RO input sheet").Range("A" & lastrow, "M" & lastrow).Merge
```

Comment: This seem to get the job done, thank you for your quick assistance.